# Choice Conflict In JavaCC. Consider Using Lookahead of 3 or more

Tags: compiler-construction, lexical-analysis, javacc

I am currently trying to build a parser for a simple programming language. The parser generates fine, but it shows this warning:

```
Warning: Choice conflict involving two expansions at
         line 238, column 7 and line 239, column 7 respectively.
         A common prefix is: "(" "("
         Consider using a lookahead of 3 or more for earlier expansion.
```

The code where the error is happening is as follows:

```java
void condition(): {}
{
    <NOT> condition() condition_prime()
    | <LPAREN> condition() <RPAREN> condition_prime()
    | expression() compare_ops() expression() condition_prime()
}

void condition_prime(): {}
{
    logical_ops() condition() condition_prime() | {}
}
```

I did it this way to eliminate left recursion but now that warning occurs. Is there any way this warning can be avoided?

The code that builds the `expression()` non-terminal is as follows:

```
void expression(): {}
{
    fragment() expression_prime()
}

void expression_prime(): {}
{
    binary_arith_op() fragment() expression_prime() | {}
}

void fragment(): {}
{
    <ID> (<LPAREN> args_list() <RPAREN>)?
    | <MINUS> <ID> 
    | <NUM> 
    | <DIGIT> 
    | <TRUE> 
    | <FALSE> 
    | <LPAREN> expression() <RPAREN>
}
```

Comment: What line is 238?  (As a side comment, questions come up about this grammar or something like it every year at the same time. It seems to be an assignment.  Ask your instructor for help.  He/she is actually being paid to educate you.)

Comment: Having separate rules for boolean and non-boolean expressions is almost always a bad idea. You're already running into trouble with lookahead, and as soon as you introduce variables to your language, the grammar will become downright ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason there is a choice conflict is that in the definition of nonterminal `condition` there are 3 choices and the second and third can both start with an`<LPAREN>`. This is because an `expression` can start with an `<LPAREN>`.

The error message suggests using a lookahead of 3 or more.  However, changing the amount of lookahead to any finite number will not be sufficient. For example if you change it to 17, that will not be enough if a `condition` starts with a left parenthesis followed by an expression that is 16 tokens long or more.

You can solve the problem with syntactic lookahead.